# Use R inside a docker container (docker run) with packages already imported

Tags: r, docker, r-sf, r-package

I use R within a docker container to run some R-scripts.

Using ***docker run***, it works quite well and fast besides the import of the packages which always take quite a while.

Especially importing the sf package takes 10 times the runtime of the actual R-script:

```
library("sf")
```

> Linking to GEOS 3.8.0, GDAL 3.0.4, PROJ 6.3.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE

Is there any possibility to fasten up the import of the packages, for example importing the files in the ***docker build*** process?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can build your docker image with `{sf}` installed at build time.

Note that it may be somewhat tricky, as `{sf}` has dependencies (e.g. GDAL, GEOS, PROJ) at system level, which in turn have their dependencies.

For an example of Dockerfile that installs a specific version of `{sf}` dependencies, consider for inspiration this one: https://github.com/jlacko/RCzechia/blob/master/data-raw/Dockerfile

What it does is:

1. it pulls R 4.1.0 version [Rocker](https://rocker-project.org/) image with R Studio
2. compiles the big three dependencies from source as my use case requires a specific version; this may be overkill in yours and takes about forever - you may want to replace this step with an install of complied binaries as in next step
3. installs system level (ubuntu) dependency binaries required for R packages
4. installs several R packages from time versioned CRAN mirror - note how Microsoft, of all companies, helpfully provides daily snapshots of CRAN. This is very helpful for reproducibility.

Your use case will likely call for a different mix of R packages, but I hope this gives you an inspiration for going forward.

Comment: I already use the spatial version of Rocker (rocker/geospatial) but still it needs to find and link sf every time!

Comment: @Squeezie what *exactly* do you mean by linking? you need sf to be available (ie. installed) or up & running (ie. already loaded)?

Comment: I need it up and imported in the best case!
When I run my docker container it starts up R which then runs the R-script which does library(sf), which does the linking to geos, gdal and so every time on and takes quite a while (much longer than the actual script)!
So either I can speed up the importing of the packages OR have R already running with all libraries loaded and run the R-script in the already opened R-session.